# Let $\sim $ be equivalence relation on $\mathbb N$ so there 4 different integers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $\sim $ be equivalence relation on $\mathbb N$ so there are $4$ different integers: $i,j,k,m$ that for all $n\in \mathbb N$ there's $t\in \{i,j,k,m\}$ such that $n \sim t$ then:

A. $1\leq \left | \left \{ \left [ n \right ]:n\in \mathbb{N} \right \} \right |\leq 4$

B. $\left | \left \{ \left [ n \right ]:n\in \mathbb{N} \right \} \right |=4$

C. $\left | \left \{ \left [ n \right ]:n\in \mathbb{N} \right \} \right |>5$

D. $0\leq \left | \left \{ \left [ n \right ]:n\in \mathbb{N} \right \} \right |\leq 4$

Can someone explain what to do here and how to get to the answer.

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given an equivalence relation on $\Bbb N$, and you are told that there are four integers that any other integer is equivalent to at least one of those.

How many equivalence classes are there? I assume that you are supposed to mark the true statements. But for a correct answer on that you will have to ask your teachers.

**HINT:** Remember that if $a\sim b$ then $[a]=[b]$. This should get you a long way in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking for the cardinality of the set of **equivalence classes**, where $n_1 \sim n_2$ if and only if $[n_1] = [n_2]$.

What can you conclude in response to the question: how many classes must exist if for every natural number is related to exactly one of $\{i, j, k, m\}$? Use the definition of an equivalence relation, how this equivalence relation is defined, and the fact that an equivalence relation *partitions* the set on which it is defined.

Note also we are given that there exist $4$ *different* (unique) integers $i, j, k, m$ such that *every natural number $n$ is equivalent to (exactly) one of $i, j, k, m$. So there are *at least* $4$ equivalence classes, and *at most four* equivalence classes under $\sim$. Why?

Comment: The problem doesn't state that every number is equivalent to *exactly* one of $\{i,j,k,m\}$, it just says it is equivalent to at least one of those. That's also true if you take $\sim\,=\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ and get only one equivalence class.